# NoSuchMethod in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ 2018.1 for several Java/Spring/Gradle projects.  On one of them, I am seeing tests that use a particular class fail with the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.company.MyClass.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Date;)V
```

But the class in question has a changed constructor such as

```
 public MyClass(String someId, String firstName, String lastName, Date dateOfBirth, String lastFour) {..}
```

I have tried changing the constructor, rebuilding, but always the tests in IntelliJ fail with this error.  Strangely, building with

> gradle clean build test

correctly runs the tests without error.  Its as if IntelliJ is not doing a clean of old class files for tests.

Comment: Does it help if you run "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  Interesting, I never noticed that option though.